# Can we approximate exponents like this?

Tags: statistics, physics, approximation

Is the following approximation valid?

$$10^{3.5 \times 10^{28}} \times 5 \times 10^{10} \underline{\approx 10^{3.5\times10^{28} + 10}} \approx 10^{3.5 \times 10^{28}}$$

The underlined part is mine, the book didn't provide any elaboration.

[This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030024288) on statistical physics uses it on page $118$, eq. $(2.91)$.

Comment: Yes, it is true that $10^a \times 10^b = 10^{(a+b)}.$  The one mistake in your posting is that you overlooked the factor of $5 \approx 10^{0.699}.$  However, I do question the use of the approximate symbol in the statement $$10^{\left[3.5 \times 10^{28}\right] + 10 + 0.699} \approx 10^{\left[3.5 \times 10^{28}\right]},$$ since the RHS is **off** by a factor greater than $10^{10}.$

Comment: This is the exact reason why I question this approximation too

Comment: That the approximation is off by a factor greater than $10^{10}$ does not matter here because the number is so huge that this factor is irrelevant. It is still an excellent approximation in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original calculation of the $3.5 \times 10^{28}$ was not an exact number itself.

Among other terms, it involved multiplying by $\frac{2 \pi e}{h^2}$ and then rounding to one decimal place, so it already probably wrong by more than $10^{26}$. In this context, a further additive adjustment of about $10.7$ is negligible in the logarithm even if it represents a multiplicative factor of $50$ thousand million in the original number.

Your book says

> If we write $10^{3.5\times 10^{28}}$ as a “$1$” followed by a string of centimetre-wide zeroes,
> we’ll have a string of digits whose length is about $37$ thousand million light
> years, or several times the extent of the observable universe.

The error caused by ignoring the $5 \times 10^{10}$ terms affects this illustration of the size by about $10.7$ centimetres, which is indeed small relative to the extent of the observable universe.

Comment: If you write $10^{28}$ like that, you only need $28$ centimetre for the zeroes.

Comment: I'm guessing it is meant to be $10^{10^{28}}$ or $10^{3.5 \times 10^{28}}$ in the quote?

Comment: Bruno - yes - $10^{28}$ would be $10000000000000000000000000000$ which is not so long.  I think it is saying $10^{28}$ zeros

Comment: I edited the quote

Answer (score 0):

First, we can simplify the left-hand side of the equation:

$10^{3.5\times10^{28}} \times 5\times10^{10} = 5 \times 10^{3.5\times10^{28} + 10}$

Now, let's compare the exponents on each side of the equation:

$3.5\times10^{28} + 10 = 3.5\times10^{28}$

Since the exponent on the right-hand side is the same as the exponent on the left-hand side, we can conclude that the approximation is valid.

This is because when multiplying two numbers with the same base, we can add their exponents:

$a^b \times a^c = a^{b+c}$

In this case, we're multiplying $10^{3.5\times10^{28}}$ and $5\times10^{10}$, which both have a base of 10. Therefore, we can add their exponents to get $3.5\times10^{28} + 10$.

Since $3.5\times10^{28} + 10$ is essentially the same as $3.5\times10^{28}$ (the difference is negligible when compared to the size of the exponent), we can make the approximation that:

$10^{3.5\times10^{28}} \times 5\times10^{10} \approx 10^{3.5\times10^{28}}$